# Query custom content scroller plugin - preventing users from scrolling down the webpage efficiently

Tags: jquery, html

I am having some trouble here. I am using this JQuery custom content scroller plugin (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) - it is great but I am facing one issue. I have disabled the mouseWheel by giving it a scroll amount of 'false' `mouseWheel:{scrollAmount:false}`. It has stopped the plug-in from scrolling whenever I scroll down/up the page, but when I do scroll down/up the webpage, the webpage gets stuck whenever the cursor hovers over the plug in. Here is the JQuery code i have so far, as follows:

```js
(function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
    
    /* 
    get snap amount programmatically or just set it directly (e.g. "273") 
    in this example, the snap amount is list item's (li) outer-width (width+margins)
    */
    var amount=Math.max.apply(Math,$("#content-1 li").map(function(){return $(this).outerWidth(true);}).get());
    
    $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({
     axis:"x",
     theme:"inset",
     enable: true,
     advanced:{
      autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true
     },
     scrollButtons:{
      enable:true,
      scrollType:"stepped"
     },
     keyboard:{scrollType:"stepped"},
     snapAmount:amount,
                 verticalScrolling: false,
                 horizontalScrolling: true,
     mouseWheel:{scrollAmount:false}
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
```

I have included a graphic in order to illustrate:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To disable mouse-wheel use:
`mouseWheel:{ enable: false }`

From [this post](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/comment-page-68/#comment-19934). I had similar issue and this solved for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer (post url: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/comment-page-67/#comment-19934)